# Choosing right control for list of items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM. In my `ViewModel` I have collection of items, for example:

```
class Item {
    string Title {get; set;}
    string Description {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to create a view, so at the beginning I would have:

```
Title1
Title2
Title3
```

If user click on one of title it will expand to show description, eg:

```
Title1
Description1
Title2
Title3
```

If user click on other title, there will be two expanded items:

```
Title1
Description1
Title2
Description2
Title3
```

This is probably very similar to `Expander` control and maybe I could use it, but I am doing it other way, to learn something new.

What control should I use for this purpose? Should that be `ItemsControl` or maybe `ListBox`?

I imagine, that if I use `ItemsControl`, I should probably extend my `Item` class to have something like `bool IsExpanded` and bind UI item visibility to that value. But maybe I could use `ListBox` and somehow bind UI item visibility to... Yeah, to what? :)

How could I do such a simple thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you need selection you should go with the `ItemsControl`, to achieve the expansion you can define such behaviour in the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`, you'd just create a lightweight Expander. The principle is to have a `ToggleButton` and bind the visibility of the content to its `IsChecked` property.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2VConv"/>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="tbutton" Content="{Binding Title}">
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                    <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                </ToggleButton>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tbutton, Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource B2VConv}}">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I bind visibility of the content to `ToggleButton.IsPressed`?

Comment: It's `IsChecked`, mixed that up; you can use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with ListBox and have `ListBox.SelectionMode="Multiple"` in it.
On the ItemcontainerStyle you can have a Trigger on the ListBox.IsSelected to make it expanded.